# What is AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport

Tags: asp.net, web-config, session-state, cookieless

Recently, I noticed about having AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 in the URL when I clear browser cookies. Upon doing a short research, I found out that it is result of cookieless attribute set to "AutoDetetct" in web.config.

The parameter 'AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport' goes away when I visit the URL again. What does 'AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1' mean?

Answer (score 6):

The AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 querystring is added automatically by ASP.NET during the cookie support detection phase. Since  cookieless attribute in the web.config file is set to "AutoDetect", the ASP.NET runtime tries to detect whether the user's browser supports cookies, and the querystring parameter is added during that process. If cookies are supported, the Session ID is kept in a cookie, and if not the Session ID is sent in the Url of all future requests by that user.

More information can be found at: https://captcha.com/doc/aspnet/faq/captcha-persistence-faq.html#persistence-querystring